# Proof of the existence of a reversible stationary distribution

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

$p$ is a finite Markov chain where $p(i,j)>0$ for all $i,j$. Prove a reversible stationary distribution exists for $p$ if

$p(i,j)p(j,k)p(k,i)=p(i,k)p(k,j)p(j,i)$ for all $i,j,k$

This question is from Durrett's Essentials of Stochastic Processes. There is a hint provided that says: Hint: fix $i$ and take $π_j = cp(i,j)/p(j,i)$ where $c$ is some constant.

I am struggling to see how to apply this hint. I want to show $c$ is $π_i$ but don't know how to get there.

Comment: Could you define a reversible stationary distribution?

Comment: Sure, a stationary distribution $π$ is reversible when it satisfies the detailed balance conditions: 

$π_i p(i,j)=π_j p(j,i), \;\; \forall i,j$

Comment: A stochastic process $X(t)$ is reversible if $(X(t_1),X(t_2),...,X(t_n))$ has the same distribution as $(X(\tau-t_1),X(\tau-t_2),...,X(\tau-t_n))$ for all $t_1,t_2,...,t_n,\tau \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: $$\sum_j\pi_jp(j,k)=c\sum_j\frac{p(i,j)p(j,k)}{p(j,i)}=c\sum_j\frac{p(i,k)p(k,j)}{p(k,i)}=c\frac{p(i,k)}{p(k,i)}\sum_jp(k,j)=c\frac{p(i,k)}{p(k,i)}=\pi_k$$

Comment: @Did  What exactly are you trying to say with the above equality?

Comment: @sir_thursday "trying to say"? Let me suggest the following experiment: write down the desired property (that $\pi$ is stationary for $p$) and compare with my comment. Done deal?